# Why ssh ask multiple passphrase at once while executing git push

Tags: windows-10, ssh, git

I'm windows user and after I updated git client (2.26.0 -> 2.38.0) the git starts to ask for multiple ssh passphrase for a single push command instead of one here is the terminal prompt

```
git push
Enter passphrase for key 'C:/Users/myUsername/.ssh/git_ssh_key': 
Enter passphrase for key 'C:/Users/myUsername/.ssh/git_ssh_key': 
Enter passphrase for key 'C:/Users/myUsername/.ssh/git_ssh_key': 
Enter passphrase for key 'C:/Users/myUsername/.ssh/git_ssh_key': 
Enter passphrase for key 'C:/Users/myUsername/.ssh/git_ssh_key': 
Enumerating objects: 26, done.
...
```

I wonder why ? and am concerned about possible security issues.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3318 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371608/why-git-push-of-lfs-git-ask-password-3-times